# PostgreSQL large number of partition tables problem using hash partitioning

Tags: postgresql

I have a very large database with more than 1.5 billion records for device data and growing.

I manage this by having a separate table for each device, about 1000 devices (tables) with an index table for daily stats. Some devices produce much more data than others, so I have tables with more than 20 million rows and others with less than 1 million.

I use indexes, but queries and data processing gets very slow on large tables.

I just upgraded to PostgreSQL 13 from 9.6 and tried to do one single table with hash partition with a least 3600 tables to import all the tables into this one and speed up the process.

But as soon as I do this, I was able to insert some rows, but when I try to query or count rows I get out of shared memory,  and max locks per transaction issues.

I tried to fine tune but didn’t succeed. I dropped the tables to 1000, but in certain operations I get the error once again, just for testing I dropped down to 100 and it works, but queries are slower with the same amount data in a stand alone table.

I tried range partition in each individual table for year period and improved but will be very messy to maintain thousands of tables with yearly ranges (note I am running in a server with 24 virtual processors and 32 GB RAM).

The question is: Is it possible to have a hash partition with more than 1000 tables? If so, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Well, the "max locks per transaction" error can easily be resolved by increasing that limit. However, partitioning should be driven by either the requirement to efficiently delete large amounts of rows _or_ by the query you need to run. If you want to use partitioning for performance reasons you need to use a partitioning key that is used in the WHERE clause of all queries (or at least all performance relevant queries). Maybe range partitioning by device would make sense. While 1000 partitions is pushing the limits, I think this should work in Postgres 13

Comment: Thanks, I just realized that the max_locks_per_transaction line was commented by default, now it works with 3653 partition tables, I copied one 5M rows table to this partitioned table and now it can count and select rows using the WHERE clause with the partitioning key, but running the same query in the original table took 253 ms while in the partitioned table took 6.5 seconds, so I think to drop the idea of a single partitioned table and figure out a range partition on each device table.